# Loading Tensorflow graph from binary file in Android application

Tags: android, python, c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to integrate TensorFlow into an Android application. Since I'm new to TensorFlow, I'm proceeding starting with very simple operations.

As a first step I created just the following model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
​
    x = tf.placeholder("float", [1, 10], name="input")
    a = tf.zeros([10, 5], dtype=tf.float32, name="a")
    y = tf.matmul(x, a, name="output")
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
​
    graph_def = g.as_graph_def()

    tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, 'models/', 'graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

This works fine. I'm able to properly get output from my C++ code (and then from Android as well).

I tried then to generate `a` by using `tf.random_normal`. It seems this is not feasible by just replacing `tf.zeros` with `tf.random_normal`. That's because `tf.zeros` returs a costant, while `tf.random_normal` not. In particular it seems I must handle it as a variable.

Idea I followed is the same proposed in other examples I've found on GitHub... so, evaluating `a` before writing the graph, as reported in code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10, 5], dtype=tf.float32), name="a")
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

a_eval = a.eval(sess)
# print here properly produces matrix in output
print a_eval
sess.close()

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 10], name="input")
    a_2 = tf.constant(a_eval, name="a_2") 
    y = tf.matmul(x, a_2, name="output")
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    graph_def = g.as_graph_def()

    tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, 'models/', 'graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

Unfortunately it seems it doesn't work due to an error occurring in reading binary file:

> Out of range: Read less bytes than requested

This is C++ code that I'm currently using for loading graph from file:

```
tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
Status load_graph_status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), filepath, &graph_def);
if (!load_graph_status.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "could not create tensorflow graph: " << load_graph_status;
    return NULL;
}
```

Hope someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you try writing out your `graph_def` with `as_text=True` and make sure that there's a node with name `"output"` in the second graph?

Comment: @mrry Apparently nothing changes, but I'm not getting a different error message: `FeedInputs: unable to find feed output input`

Comment: @mrry It seems I've found a clearer error (and updated question accordingly). While loading graph from binary I forgot to check output status. It seems graph is not loaded properly, since returned status is always: `Out of range: Read less bytes than requested`. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: @mrry I solved the issue. I was downloading model from a remote url and I've found an error in reading file content (it was truncated in some cases). Incredible how this didn't cause any problem with my first experiments. Thanks a lot in any case for your support. It gave me some inspiration.